# Find from last blank line to string using regex

Tags: regex, jedit

I need to do a search in jEdit for a string starting with the end of the last empty line up to another string:

```
blah
blah 
blah 
blah
blah 
empty line
empty line
empty line *start here*
blah 
blah
blah blah blah
blah
blah
blah ------ Running ------
```

The idea is to do a search and replace to remove everything (i've bolded) before the string 
------ Running ------ but not the lines or strings before that last line.

Can someone suggest the proper regex to find from end of last line up to the beginning of the string 
------ Running ------ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex and then remove the matched string with an empty string.

```
(?s)(?<=\n)(?:(?!\n\n).)*\n(?=[^\n]+------ Running ------)
```

Java regex would be,

```
(?s)(?<=\\n)(?:(?!\\n\\n).)*\\n(?=[^\\n]+------ Running ------)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ6tR0/1)

Comment: This: (?s)(?<=\n)(?:(?!\n\n).)*\n(?=[^\n]+------ Running ------) worked! Thanks